# Using sockets outside their dedicated 'connection' scope

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making a node.js app with sockets.io.

The logic of my app needs to communicate to client through their respective sockets, but the problem with sockets is they're in their own "domain" of code.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // socket object is only available here
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

See?

I tried to export this socket object out

```
var Sockets = []
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  Sockets[socket.handshake.user.id] = socket;
});
```

Now it's available outside

```
function myLogic(userid) {
  Sockets[userid].emit('free!')
}
```

But I'm facing weird bugs because it's probably not supposed to be used this way... like new connections make new `socket` objects but previous ones still exist somewhere in memory and they still react when their `.on('..'` gets fired...

What is the correct way to use `socket`s outside of their respective `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){}` scope?

Comment: Why don't you just store only the socket id (socket.id) in the Sockets array 
and when you have to emit something do: 

function myLogic(userid)
{
  io.sockets.clients(socket.room)[userid].emit('free!')
  // Another way to do the same would be
  io.sockets.socket(userid).emit('free');
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question: if you want to use sockets outside of their respective "io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){} scope", you have to access them through the io object --> io.sockets.socket(socketId), where socketId is stored somewhere.

Comment: I had to use `io.sockets.sockets[socketId]` to get to the socket. The `socketId` can be determined using `socket.id`.

Comment: However, this does not seem to scale well, so I am yet to figure out a solution when you have more than one socket.

Answer (score 0):

Make a setup function for your module and pass it the initialized socket thing. Ie. something like this from *main.js*:

`var server = require('http').createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
  var myModule = require('./myModule').setup(io);`

Then in your *myModule.js* save a reference to the `io` object:

`var localIo;
  exports.setup = function(io) {
    localIo = io;
  };
  // Then after in your other code....
  function myLocalFunction(myData) {
    localIo.sockets.volatile.emit('myevent', {data: myData});
  };`